Read all messages from simple, small EventHub with PowerShell
We have a small Azure Event Hubs Instance (infinite retention with a few hundred events) and would like to view/list all events from offset 0 with PowerShell.
We can POST new messages to https://$EventHubsNamespace.servicebus.windows.net/$EventHubsName/messages. Is there a way to read all messages/events?

You can use the Azure.Messaging.EventHubs package: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/samples/Sample05_ReadingEvents.md#read-events-from-all-partitions-with-a-maximum-wait-time

As aside, ideally it's much easier to consume the events using an azure function, event hub trigger makes it really easy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-powershell

You cannot read events via the REST API; you'd need to use AMQP to do so.  I concur with the comment suggesting Azure.Messaging.EventHubs - it targets netstandard2.0 and can be used with a PowerShell host.
We don't generally recommend using EventHubConsumerClient.ReadEventsAsync for production scenarios, but it seems like a good fit here, given the following assumptions:

You don't want to retain state; you'll always want to read from the beginning of the stream.

There are "a few hundred events" in the hub and scattered across partitions.  You're not expecting that number to grow significantly.

You aren't concerned with fairness when reading from partitions; given the small number of events, performance and throughput aren't a concern so you don't care if the pattern of reads favors a given partition or two until you hit the end.


If the above assumptions hold, the Read events from all partitions sample demonstrates basic usage.  Unfortunately, we don't have PowerShell-based examples, so you'll have to translate from C#.

To complement Jesse Squire's helpful answer with the implementation that handles an IAsyncIEnumerable<PartitionEvent> returned by ReadEventsAsync(), because there is no await foreach in PowerShell you need to re-implement the logic manually, which can translate to the following:
using namespace Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.Consumer

Add-Type -Path path\to\Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.dll

try {
    # you need to pick the right overload here, if using a SAS key for example
    # you can get your EventHub connection string from:
    # Settings -> Shared access policies ->
    #      Pick the right policy (at least `Listen` permission) ->
    #      Copy the `Connection string-primary key`
    $consumer = [EventHubConsumerClient]::new(
        $consumerGroup,
        $connectionString,
        $eventHubName)

    # here if using default CancellationToken you can call `ReadEventsAsync()` with no arguments
    # see the documentation for other overloads
    $enumerator = $consumer.ReadEventsAsync()
    while ($enumerator.MoveNextAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult()) {
        $evt.Current.Data.EventBody.ToString() | ConvertFrom-Json
    }
}
finally {
    if ($consumer) {
        $null = $consumer.DisposeAsync().AsTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult()
    }
}

As aside, I'd personally recommend you to look into Azure Event Hubs trigger for Azure Functions which makes consuming the events much easier.
